Custom Sort Order Using Distinct & Case Clauses
Hi  I'm having difficulty in using the order by case statement when using alongside distinct keyword. Following is the table
Table with Data
Now in order to achieve custom sort order I'm using the following query
SELECT  state_name
FROM state_master
GROUP by state_name
order by
case 
    WHEN state_name = 'Goa' THEN 1
    WHEN state_name = 'Puducherry' THEN 2
    ELSE 3
END,
CASE 
        WHEN state_name NOT IN ('Goa', 'Puducherry') THEN state_name
        ELSE NULL
    END;

This yields the correctly sorted output of
Correctly Sorted Output
Now If I want to make sure that the values selected are distinct as well ( no duplicate records )
Then I'm facing error in sql query
SELECT  DISTINCT state_name
FROM state_master
GROUP by state_name
order by
case 
    WHEN state_name = 'Goa' THEN 1
    WHEN state_name = 'Puducherry' THEN 2
    ELSE 3
END,
CASE 
        WHEN state_name NOT IN ('Goa', 'Puducherry') THEN state_name
        ELSE NULL 
    END;

The error i'm getting
Error Mesaage

Where am I going wrong?
How can I fix it when distinct is applied to single column?
How can I fix this query if i want to apply distinct on multiple columns?

Thanks.
Everything I tried I have listed above, unable to figure this issue out.

See Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? and Conditional ORDER BY

You can change this to do a DISTINCT subquery and then put your order by in the outer query.  The error you are getting is because you cant do order by unless it is in your select list.  If you do the subqueries then it should work.

I think the problem has nothing to do with your sorting:

Now If I want to make sure that the values selected are distinct as well ( no duplicate records )

Your GROUP BY is already making sure there are no duplicate values. This makes the DISTINCT redundant, and removing it will eliminate the error. The same will hold true if you GROUP BY multiple columns. Using DISTINCT instead of GROUP BY will potentially introduce issues when trying to ORDER BY.
But you can also consider using a CTE or a subquery to distinct de-duplicating from sorting altogether:
;WITH dedupe AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT state_name /* , other columns */
    FROM state_master
)
SELECT state_name /* , other columns */
  FROM dedupe
 ORDER BY /* have a blast here */;


Your first set of the CASE statement would likely need to go in 'SELECT' - doing it this way returns no case results.
Instead try
SELECT  DISTINCT state_name,
case 
    WHEN state_name = 'Goa' THEN 1
    WHEN state_name = 'Puducherry' THEN 2
    ELSE 3
    END
FROM state_master
order by
CASE 
        WHEN state_name NOT IN ('Goa', 'Puducherry') THEN state_name
        ELSE NULL 
    END;

Also, 'GROUP BY' should be used when you are using aggregate functions. Your query doesn't contain any so it really isn't necessary.

Same issue persists with this query - ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.
